# Padding around image programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I need to create a component which displays an image with a label in swift.

I created a class which extends `UIStackView` and placed an `ImageView` and a `UILabel` and it works.

**Problem** : the result is ugly, I need to add some padding around the `UIImage`. I tried to include the image in a `UIView` that is bigger than the `UIImage` but it make the image disappear! At runtime, this warning message is displayed :

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x60000009e820 h=--& v=--& UIImageView:0x7fea7fc02850.width == 0   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400009b4e0 UIImageView:0x7fea7fc02850.width == 40   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400009b4e0 UIImageView:0x7fea7fc02850.width == 40   (active)>
```

So, for a reason I don't understand, the image automatically gets a constraint `width = 0` which discards the constraint `width = 40`

Here is the code:

```
class HeaderView: UIStackView {

    var label: UILabel = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    func setup(title: String, image: UIImage?) {
        axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal
        let imgView = UIImageView()
        imgView.image = image!
        imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

        let paddedView = UIView()
        paddedView.addSubview(imgView)
        paddedView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        paddedView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

        addArrangedSubview(paddedView)

        label.text = title
        addArrangedSubview(label)
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot say I am sure but might be problem with alignment and distribution of the stack view( try to set alignment to .center). As for breaking constraint I  usually lower priority for height and width constraints as you want to let the stack view handle their visibility.

Comment: Also you should align both axis of image to its superview as you want to have the image in the center of your padded view

Comment: There are times a `UIStackView` actually *complicates* things more than needed. Is this one? Would a "container" view - basically a `UIView` or even ` `UILayoutGuide` with two subviews - be a better answer? Put *both* your `UIImageView` and `UILabel` in it. Add constraints to *it* appropriately. Now you just need to layout this container. (I personally stay away from stack/collection views just because of this. In making layout issues "easier" - and in many times they can and do... they make for unexpected behavior in other moments.)

Comment: @dfd I did not know about `UILayoutGuide`, thanks. I can make a generic component that adds padding to a UIView by nesting the view in a horizontal UIStackView with 2 empty UIView that work as horizontal "spacers“ and then nesting this in a vertical UIStackView with 2 other empty UIView as vertical "spacers". It works but it is ugly. It seems to me that UILayoutGuide is intended to replace those dummy spacers but I cannot figure out how to write this. Can you help?

Comment: `UILayoutGuides` are exactly that - a replacement for invisible "spacer" `UIViews`. Here's the tutorial that taught me (Swift 3 but pretty much the same as Swift 4): https://useyourloaf.com/blog/goodbye-spacer-views-hello-layout-guides/ If there's something I can help, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false to avoid conflicts with Auto Layout ones.
- The position of your `imgView` in `paddedView` is ambiguous. It would be better to constraint edges of `imgView` to `paddedView` instead of direct setting `imgView` size.
- As @Luzo mentioned you need to change stack view alignment because it's `.fill` by default.

Here is the code

```
func setup(title: String, image: UIImage?) {
    axis = .vertical
    alignment = .center

    label.text = title

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let containerView = UIView()
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    containerView.addSubview(imageView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 10.0),
        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10.0),
        imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10.0),
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10.0),
        containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),
        containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0)
    ])

    stackView.addArrangedSubview(containerView)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Also, grouping constraints like that is elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Set imgView , paddedView and label **translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints** property to **false**

--- Aslo

give the imageView top , bottomm , leading and trailing constraints after lowering priority of width and height

Comment: The warning message disappeared but the image still does not appear. I am sure that the image exists because if I add it directly (instead of adding the padded view), it works. Note : I set the property to `false` instead of `NO` because the code is in Swift, not objective-C.